# How to predict test data from a training model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have made a logistic regression model to predict the loan status of an entry i.e. Y or N. I think it works for the training data but when I apply it to the test data it fails.

I think I narrowed down the problem to the Married column in the test data set there is missing data for the married data but the test set is complete

This is the function I used for the imputation

```
def impute_married(cols):
    Married = cols[0]

    if pd.isnull(Married):
        return 'unknownMarriedStatus'
    else:
        return Married
```

So when its used on the test data there is no unknownMarriedStatus which is why its not working on the test set

This next section converts the data for the model.

```
my_dict = {'0':'zero','1':'one','2':'two','3':'three','3+':'threePlus', 
np.nan: 'missing'}
def convert_data(dataset):
    temp_data = dataset.copy()
    temp_data.Dependents = temp_data.Dependents.map(my_dict)
    temp_data['Gender'] = temp_data[['Gender']].apply(impute_gender,axis=1)
    temp_data['Married'] = temp_data[['Married']].apply(impute_married,axis=1)
    temp_data['Self_Employed'] = temp_data[['Self_Employed']].apply(impute_self_employed,axis=1)
    temp_data['Credit_History'] = temp_data[['Credit_History']].apply(impute_Credit_History,axis=1)

    dependents = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Dependents'],drop_first=True)
    gender = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Gender'],drop_first=True)
    married = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Married'],drop_first=True)
    education = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Education'],drop_first=True)
    self_employed = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Self_Employed'],drop_first=True)
    credit_history = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Credit_History'],drop_first=True)
    property_area = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Property_Area'],drop_first=True)
    #loan_status = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Loan_Status'],drop_first=True)
    loan_band = pd.get_dummies(temp_data['Loan_Band'],drop_first=True)



    temp_data.drop(['Loan_ID', 'ApplicantIncome', 'CoapplicantIncome', 'LoanAmount',
   'Loan_Amount_Term', 'Gender','Married','Dependents','Education','Self_Employed','Credit_History',
 'Property_Area','Loan_Band'],axis=1,inplace=True)

    temp_data = pd.concat([temp_data,dependents,gender,married, education, self_employed, credit_history, property_area, loan_band ],axis=1)

    temp_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    return temp_data


    return temp_data

train_dataset = convert_data(train)
```

Then

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = 
train_test_split(train_dataset.drop('Loan_Status',axis=1), 

train_dataset['Loan_Status'], 
test_size=0.30, 
                                            random_state=101)
```

next is the logistic regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver="lbfgs")
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = logmodel.predict(X_test)

predictions = logmodel.predict(train_dataset.drop('Loan_Status', axis = 1))
```

this then gives me the report

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(train_dataset['Loan_Status'],predictions))
```

the next part is the report

```
  precision    recall  f1-score   support
N       0.86      0.45      0.59       192
Y       0.80      0.97      0.87       422

avg / total       0.82      0.81      0.79       614
```

next for the accuracy

```
print('Accuracy of logistic regression classifier on test set: 
{:.2f}'.format(logmodel.score(X_test, y_test)))
pd.crosstab(y_test, y_pred, rownames=['Actual Result'], colnames= 
['Predicted Result'])

test_dataset = convert_data(test) 
predictions = logmodel.predict(test_dataset.drop('Loan_Status', axis = 1))
```

this then gives me the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-474a34c1dffa> in <module>()
      1 #predictions = logmodel.predict(test_dataset)
----> 2 predictions = logmodel.predict(test_dataset.drop('Loan_Status', axis = 1))

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in predict(self, X)
    322             Predicted class label per sample.
    323         """
--> 324         scores = self.decision_function(X)
    325         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
    326             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py in decision_function(self, X)
    303         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
    304             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
--> 305                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    306 
    307         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 23 features per sample; expecting 24
```

Here is the shapes of the data sets

```
train.shape
```

(614, 17)

```
train_dataset.shape
```

614, 25)

```
test.shape
```

(367, 16)

```
test_dataset.shape
```

(367, 23)

```
train_dataset.columns
```

Index(['Loan_Status', 'ApplicantIncome_log', 'CoapplicantIncome_exp',
       'LoanAmount_log', 'one', 'threePlus', 'two', 'zero', 'Male',
       'unknownGender', 'Yes', 'unknownMarriedStatus', 'Not Graduate', 'Yes',
       'unknownEmploymentStatus', 'Yes', 'unknownCredHist', 'Semiurban',
       'Urban', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H'],
      dtype='object')

```
test_dataset.columns
```

Index(['ApplicantIncome_log', 'CoapplicantIncome_exp', 'LoanAmount_log', 'one',
       'threePlus', 'two', 'zero', 'Male', 'unknownGender', 'Yes',
       'Not Graduate', 'Yes', 'unknownEmploymentStatus', 'Yes',
       'unknownCredHist', 'Semiurban', 'Urban', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H'],
      dtype='object')

​

I want to make it so I have a logistic regression model working on the train data and then I can apply it to the test data
I was told my summary stats are based on the whole of the `test.csv` dataset, but I trained against this dataset so my score will be inflated. But I dont understand what was meant by that or how to fix it.

Comment: if you use your second line `predictions = logmodel.predict(test_dataset.drop('Loan_Status', axis = 1))
` it should work. Your error traceback and the code is not consitent. please recheck

Comment: @VenkatachalamN sorry for the delayed reply I think I found the error but have no idea how to fix it. It is to do with the married column, I updated the post to show this. Basically  a new column gets added when the data is missing but how am i supposed to deal with missing data in the train set, when the test.set is complete and the imputed train set then gets an extra column

Comment: @VenkatachalamN I just added the shapes in case that may help understand it better